# inserting values from on table to another in sql server 2008 with one field should be incremented

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
declare @cid int

set @cid=(select ISNULL(MAX(cid),0)+1 from CustInfo)
insert into CustInfo(CID,CTypeId,CustNo,Regdate,
                     DOB,CCertID,CCertNo,CompId,PostedBy,PostedOn) 
(select @cid,1,0,'2012-9-10',
        dob,ccertid,ccertno,0,null,null 
 from updateCust3)
```

I have used above code to insert values from table updateCust3 to table UpdateCustInfo.
In this case the CID field should be incremented by one at each insert. I have used the above code but the cid doesn't seem to increase so the error is duplicate value for the primary key. So how can I increase the value of cid? Since the change in table property is not allowed I cannot use identity property.

Comment: is there any reason you didn't use identity column?

Comment: The change in the table is not allowed So I have to increase CId mannually.

Comment: If two users execute the code at the same time they could end up with the same value in `@cid` and causing primary key violation. You should use an identity column instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
declare @cid int

set @cid=(select ISNULL(MAX(cid),0)+1 from CustInfo)
insert into CustInfo(CID,CTypeId,CustNo,Regdate,
                     DOB,CCertID,CCertNo,CompId,PostedBy,PostedOn) 
select @cid+row_number() over (order by (select 0)),1,0,'2012-9-10',
        dob,ccertid,ccertno,0,null,null 
 from updateCust3)
```

**Edit:** As MikaelEriksson mentioned in the comment, this has the risk, if you users are simultaneously trying to update the table, it will error out..

Answer (score 1):

have used a temp table to demonstrate. This is a better way to work to avoid errors when used by multiple users

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE               
        (               
           CTypeId INT identity (1,1)
           ,CustNo int
           ,DOB datetime           
         ,Regdate datetime
         ,CCertID int
              ,CCertNo int
       ,CompId int
    ,PostedBy varchar(100)
    ,PostedOn datetime
        )      

            INSERT @Table    
            select 1,0,'2012-9-10',
            dob,ccertid,ccertno,0,null,null 
     from updateCust3
```